# How to filter information in Java JTable.

Tags: java

I have a JTable with 3 columns. date, Description and amount. 
In the table I have to put a filter. Actually I want to show data in the table only between a period selected by user.The user can decide whether to display the information in a single day, a week, a month,or a year.Can you help mee?? I don't have any idea.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You create a [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) that only contains the rows shown in the JTable.  Your code determines which rows are added to the TableModel and which rows are not added to the TableModel.

Comment: JTable has a filter (and sorting) API, see [JTable, filtering and sorting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details

Answer (score 0):

This should be implemented in [TableModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html)

Comment: No it shouldn't, the JTable has a filtering API